# Development process for Code First Entity Framework and SQL Server Data Tools Database Projects

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-data-tools

I have been using Database First Entity Framework (EDMX) and SQL Server Data Tools Database Projects in combination very successfully - change the schema in the database and 'Update Model from Database' to get them into the EDMX. I see though that Entity Framework 7 will be dropping the EDMX format and I am looking for a new process that will allow me to use Code First in Combination with Database Projects.

Lots of my existing development and deployment processes rely on having a database project that contains the schema. This goes in source control is deployed along with the code and is used to update the production database complete with data migration using pre and post deployment scripts. I would be reluctant to drop it.

I would be keen to split one big EDMX into many smaller models as part of this work. This will mean multiple Code First models referencing the same database.

Assuming that I have an existing database and a database project to go with it - I am thinking that I would start by using the following wizard to create an initial set of entity and context classes - I would do this for each of the models.

```
Add | New Item... | Visual C# Items | Data | ADO.NET Entity Data Model | Code first from database
```

My problem is - where do I go from there? How do I handle schema changes? As long as I can get the database schema updated, I can use a schema compare operation to get the changes into the project.

These are the options that I am considering.

1. Make changes in the database and use the wizard from above to regenerate. I guess that I would need to keep any modifications to the entity and/or context classes in partial classes so that they do not get overwritten. Automating this with a list of tables etc to include would be handy. Powershell or T4 Templates maybe? [SqlSharpener](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener) (suggested by Keith in comments) looks like it might help here. I would also look at [disabling all but the checks for database existence and schema compatibility](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/) here, as suggested by Steve Green in the comments.
2. Make changes in code and use migrations to get these changes applied to the database. From what I understand, not having models map cleanly to database schemas (mine don't) might pose problems. I also see some complaints on the net that migrations do not cover all database object types - this was also my experience when I played around with Code First a while back - unique constraints I think were not covered. Has this improved in Entity Framework 7?
3. Make changes in the database and then use migrations as a kind of comparison between code and the database. See what the differences are and adjust the code to suit. Keep going until there are no differences.
4. Make changes manually in both code and the database. Obviously, this is not very appealing.

Which of these would be best? Is there anything that I would need to know before trying to implement it? Are there any other, better options?

Comment: If you do go the non-migration route, you can at least apply a check at startup to make sure you're in sync. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/

Comment: Consider [SqlSharpener](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener) to help you with option #1.

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene. That really does sound like it would be worthwhile doing. I added your suggestion to point 1.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. SqlSharpener does look interesting. I will check it out.

Comment: What did you decide?  I'm faced with a similar situation.  I was using SSDT with database first. Decided to switch to code first with migrations to simplify the development workflow.  Now faced with deploying to production (azure) and the need for finer control, I'm investigating code first without migrations and possibly re-introducing SSDT.

Comment: @user1843640 - I added an answer that outlines the path that we ended up taking.

Answer (score 3):

So the path that we ended up taking was to create some T4 templates that generate both a DbContext and our entities. We provide the entity T4 a list of tables from which to generate entities and have a syntax to indicate that the entity based on one table should inherit from the entity based on another. Custom code goes in partial classes. So our solution looks most like my option 1 from above.

Also, we started out generating fluent configuration in OnModelCreating in the DbContext but have swapped to using attributes on the Entities (where attributes exist - HasPrecision was one that we had to use fluent configuration for). We found that it is more concise and easier to locate the configuration for a property when it is right there decorating that property.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  It's useful to see how others are handling situations like this and how they are dealing with concerns presented by real-world applications.